# Facebook's last-modified header on assets always Mon, 01 Jan 2001 08:00:00 GMT

Tags: facebook, http

I noticed on a lot (all?) of Facebook's CSS and JS assets have a `last-modified` response header of `Mon, 01 Jan 2001 08:00:00 GMT`.

What value would they be getting out of these all using the same last-modified date? Is it to help with their caching strategy?Maybe obscuring actual date changes for some sort of security benefit? If it's either of these (or something else), how does it provide value?

Comment: Mainly caching. Cache busting is done via a change of resource URLs when necessary.

Comment: What value does it provide to the caching strategy? I recognize they do cache busting through changing URLs.

Comment: I guess it just simplifies the process ... they’ll never have to bother finding out when a file/resource was actually last modified to send the “correct” value; instead everything is presented as if it was "set in stone from the beginning of time" (resp. 2001, in this case) - less hassle for both sides.